# Sqlite db security

Tags: database, security, sqlite

Im building an app which uses Sqlite DB. 
Users can enter their information into the db and retrieve them. 
However, I want them to be able to backup the sqlite db.
What I did was putting the sqlite db in the documents folder, so they could retrieve it out using iTunes. 
For example if the ipad is faulty, i want them to be able to transfer the sqlite db to another ipad.

The problem now is, I dont want them to know the information inside the db, should say the db structure. 
So how can I build a db that is able to read by my application only? and when they use sqlite browser to open, they wont be able to see anything. 
I'm looking for something simple. Possible to have the db to prompt a password before opening it?

Comment: SQLite security? Hahaha. Don't let other people have access to it. One solution is to export/backup to a [well-defined] XML format or a "fake structured" SQLite database file. Or to *encrypt* the back-up database (e.g. in ZIP+password). Or just change the file extension (this will work for most people I'd imagine). Another solution is use a modified SQLite version like FF and then *break it* from being compatible with other SQLite programs (e.g. by adding a bunch of "extra stuff") at the end. I don't recommend the last approach at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the [link](http://sqlcipher.net/) to your answer, SQLCipher is the best thing, which will encrypt the whole database and if any one get the database from the iOS device, any how , still it will prompt for a password otherwise is will not allow user to see the same. even with Command prompt the user will not be able to see the database.

Hope this will be usefull....

Comment: For the phone to be able to decrypt it, the key has to be somewhere in the app, which means a determined user would be able to eventually get at it. This answer gives a false sense of security.

Comment: The code no one can get, so how any one shall acces your key ? other wise you can get the key from the Web Services.

Comment: @ceejayoz there's no absolute security anyway and using something hardware-specific as the key (IMEI and alike) would drive away 99,99% of regular users and 90% of hackers. And for serious security the data should not be stored on device in the first place.

Comment: @ceejayoz what do you mean by false sense of security ?

Comment: Actually zip + password sounds like a good idea. im not storing something very important, i just want most of the people give up trying to sneak my sqlite, without spending some time. you guys try Ziparchive before? it offers zip + password.

Comment: @V.V A good assembly debugger can get straight past that.  Even if you encrypt the key in the program you can use a debugger to halt the program right as it tries to access the DB then read the key right out of memory.  No need to ever see the source code.  To an experienced hacker this could be <5 minutes.  A colleague of mine had to do that once after he lost his own key.

Comment: This answer is not wrong. All application has the key to decrypt password somewhere in app. Web, desktop, mobile. That is normal...