# should I hash username in OTP based two factor authentication database?

Tags: database, sqlite, authentication, ssh

I currently dealing with a ssh two factor authentication plugin.

It can be used like this:

> $ ssh localhost
>   password: [ssh password]
>   Name: [your name]
>   OTPCode: [your code]

there is a list of username and OTP Secret in sqlite db.

if the sqlite db leaks, it is dangerous. should I hash the username and add a nick name to distinguish  a which one is which. will this design cause any problem or is it neccesary?

Comment: SQLite itself is unsafe. Recommend reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044261/sqlite-db-security

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, if someone gets hold of the database in the clear with the secrets in it, they aren't going to be too bothered about hashed/obfuscated usernames. They already have the secret information.

An attacker could realistic generate all the OTPs against all the secrets from the database in a fraction of a second and then try them all for any given username. Moreover if they have sniffed the username in the past and know when they authenticated (For TOTP), they can create all the OTPs for all the secrets in the database for that window and then see which secret corresponds to that user.

Basically if you loose your token's shared secret, loosing the corresponding username is going to be the least of your worries.

Focus on locking down the database or even better getting the authentication mechanism off of the machine.